# Switch en JavaScript que devuelva "number"

Tags: javascript, switch

a ver si me podéis echar una mano.
En un ejercicio de JavaScript me piden escribir una sentencia switch que siempre devuelva "number". He intentado muchas cosas, pero realmente no entiendo como es...

el código que me dan es este:

```
       function switchStatement() {

       //Write your switch statement within this function

       }

       switchStatement();
```

¿Cómo tendría que poner? he intentado varias opciones, pero realmente no entiendo...por ejemplo;

```
      function switchStatement(number) {

      switchStatement; "number";
      console.log("It's a number");



             }

             switchStatement();
```

gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo la idea del ejercicio, pero si quieres que siempre devuelva "number", pues ignoras la variable y los cases, y siempre devuelves el valor por defecto, así:

```js
function switchStatement() {
  switch(true){ //True porque no queremos comparar nada (siempre devolvemos lo mismo no?)
    default: //Como no hay cases, se ejecuta el default
      return "number";
  }
}

console.log(switchStatement());
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un **`switch`** para el tipo de dato que recibe tu función, en este caso verificamos si el tipo de dato es **`number`** o **`string`** con el método [**`typeof()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), dependiendo de esto entrará al **`case`** de tu switch:

```js
var numero = 4;
var texto = "4";

function switchStatement(e) {
  switch(typeof(e)){ // verificamos el tipo de dato
      case "number": return typeof(e); // si el tipo de dato es "number", retorna "number"
      break;
      case "string": return typeof(e); // si el tipo de dato es "string", retorna "string"
      break;
  }
}

console.log(switchStatement(numero));
console.log(switchStatement(texto));
```

Comment: Pero no se supone que la idea es que siempre devuelva "number"... este devuelve "string"... Aunque la verdad no se si yo comprendí bien el tema... porque la funcion "original" no recibe parámetros... Yo creo que hay algo en la pregunta que está ambiguo...

Comment: Bueno, el "number" que siempre recibirá es cuando el tipo de dato es "number", y aquí es donde traté de explicar cómo sería un switch con los tipos de datos (solo que fui por ambos lados, si es "number" o "string")...

Answer (score 0):

Primero decirte que yo he tenido el mismo problema con la misma pregunta. Imagino que estás en el Developers from Euskadi, no? Es una pregunta muy liante.

Mira, el problema de este ejercicio se soluciona cambiando console.log por return, es decir, en vez de imprimir el resultado, hacemos return.
Si tienes cualquier duda, me dices. Un saludo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Exactamente, estoy en Developers from Euskadi. Al final pude resolver el ejercicio, pero me costó entenderlo al principio... Al menos he seguido hacia adelante y bueno, estoy haciendo lo que puedo porque la verdad que JavaScript me está costando más de lo que yo pensaba xD